# How do I get correct path by absolute or relative path?

Tags: python

My file structure is as follows:

```
kkg/
  builder/test.py
  builder/data
  api/api.py
  __init__py
```

'kkg' is my package name, and in **init**.py some function are defined, and implementations of these function are written api.py.

In test.py, I have:

```
import kkg
kkg.load('builder/data/')
```

Inside the 'load' of the api.py, I have code:

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
...

for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(abspath, data_path)
```

The data_path is the parameter 'builder/data/' passed from test.py. The path.join reports an error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/comin/kkg/kkg/api/data/people.csv
```

The correct data path, if parsed properly, should be:

```
/Users/comin/kkg/kkg/data/people.csv
```

I run the 'test.py' inside the builder/ directory. I think the reason there is an unnecessary 'api' in the path generated is because the code piece where error occurs in the api.py.

Perhaps I shouldn't use the join(abspath, data_path) to get the absolute directory. How to get the path correctly parsed?

EDIT:

I changed the path parameter:

```
kkg.load('../builder/data/')
```

but then this code failed:

```
if not os.path.isdir(data_path):
        raise ValueError('data_path must be a directory, not file name!')
```

Why does it raise an error when I added '..' to the path? It is not considered as a directory due to the '..'?

Comment: why not just `print(file_path)`

Comment: What do you mean? The error message already shows the wrong path generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want the parent directory I think

```
abspath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))
```

you seem to be struggling with this more than you should...it might be easier to  just do

`path_to_data_file_folder = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])`

then call it with `python main.py /path/to/data/folder`

Comment: Yes. That should work. But api.py is my interface implementation. Probably I shouldn't assume users call the function at a specific place.

Comment: this makes no assumptions about where the user calls it from ... only that the data folder is in the parent directory of /api ...

Comment: Strange, your code generates this: /Users/comin/kkg/kkg/, which is not working.

Comment: yes... that is exactly what you had but + /api ... so it goes to the parent folder of /api .. which is where you showed your data folder to be also located  so then when you `os.path.join(abspath,data_file)` you get the path to your data file

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to use `pathlib` over `os` library:

```py
# api/api.py

from pathlib import Path

KKG_FOLDER = Path(__file__).parent.parent
DATA_FOLDER = KKG_FOLDER / 'builder/data'

print(DATA_FOLDER)
```

This is more verbose and easier to understand.

Comment: This is a very nice solution.

Comment: `pathlib` is very clear and object oriented than using `os` which does to much. Take a look at [Why you should be using pathlib](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/)